# C# String.Format - nesting part of formatting string

Tags: c#, string, nested, decimal

I need to format variable decimal places with string.Format.

My input can be as following: `5.0000000`, I know number of decimals I need to use i.e. `3`, so obviously desired output should be `5.000`.

Due to some very specific environment string.Format is the only method I can use. I created a function which based on number of decimals can return part of formatting string, i.e. for `3` that would be `000`.

My idea was to *nest* a part of formatting string within formatting string. Means doing something like:

`{0:0.{1}}`, where `{1}` would be `000`.

This however brings FormatException. Is that possible to achieve at all?

Thanks for help!

Comment: What is exactly your imput? is it string, float, double, decimal?

Comment: My input is decimal

Answer (score 3):

I think you can all do in one step:

```
decimal d = 5;
int n = 3;
string str = string.Format("{0:0."+ new string('0', n) +"}", d);
```

Answer (score 1):

it is not the pretty way but you can combine two diferent formating ways:

```
string.Format($"{{0:N{number_of_decimals}}}", value);
```

strange but working

Answer (score 0):

Define the following method:

```
public static String GetFormat(Int32 decimals)
{
    // let's clamp the input to prevent abuses
    if (decimals < 0)
        decimals = 0;
    else if (decimals > 10)
        decimals = 10;

    if (decimals == 0)
        return "{0:0}";

    return String.Concat("{0:0.", (new String('0', decimals))), "}";
}
```

Then:

```
Double value = 45.355d;
Int32 decimals = 3;

String text = String.Format(GetFormat(decimals), value);
```

Comment: I am guessing the OP means he wants the number of decimal places to be 
a user-defined setting

Comment: Ah damn! Editing!

Comment: The thing is that it's not always 3. Can be 3, can be 0, can be 10 and so on ;)

Comment: Answer edited, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

If your input is a string, parse it as a float, convert it to an int and apply your function to in String.Format parameters:

```
  float x;
  float.TryParse(input, out x);
```

If your input is already a float, there is no need to do this. Then,

```
String.Format("{0}.{1}", (int)x, yourFunction(x, number_of_decimals);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use extended method:

```
public static class ExtendedMethod
{
    public static string DecimalFormat(this decimal input,int decimals)
    {
      return string.Format({"0." + new string('0', decimals)+"}", input);
      //or return input.ToString("0." + new string('0', decimals));
    }
}
```

Then:

```
 string result = yourDecimal.DecimalFormat(3);
```